# Escape sequence incorrect

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern that I want to match, but the compiler says that it is incorrect. How should I correct make the scape sequence in java?

This is the pattern:

```
String patter = "\/\/s.ytimg.com\/yts\/jsbin\/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z\/html5player.js"
```

Comment: Are you sure you need those ``\`` before `/` (`/` is not special in String or regex)?

Comment: yes because the pattern I'm looking for is build that way.

Comment: On the other hand, the full stop character *does* properly need escaping, as it matches any character (except newline) when not escaped. In this context, I suppose that you don't worry about false positives, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case where `\` is used, it needs to be duplicated, as `\` is used to escape special sequences, for example `\n` to create a newline.  `\\` is equivalent to a single `\` in the actual url.

For your actual URL, use this:

```
String patter = "\\/\\/s.ytimg.com\\/yts\\/jsbin\\/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z\\/html5player.js"
```

However, if you were trying to escape the `/` character, that is unnecessary.  You can just use this:

```
String patter = "//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z/html5player.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because there is no such escape character as `\/`. Common escape characters are these:

- `\n` newline
- `\t` tab
- ...

To embed a literal `\` in a string, you need to use `\\`, for example:

```
String pattern = "\\/\\/s.ytimg.com\\/yts\\/jsbin\\/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z\\/html5player.js";
```

But actually, I don't really see why you need `\` there at all. I think what you *really* need is most probably no `\` at all:

```
String pattern = "//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z/html5player.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape `\` then you need to make it double like `\\`. You may try this:

```
String patter = "\\/\\/s.ytimg.com\\/yts\\/jsbin\\/html5player-en_US-vfllxLx6Z\\/html5player.js";
```